# How to move all files with a certain file extension from subdirectories to a single directory

Tags: shell-script, files

I have text files in certain sub folders like `home/andhra1/node1/*.txt` files and `home/andhra1/noden/*.txt` and `home/andhra2/node1/*.txt`.
I have to all files from different sub directories to one directory.

below is the shell script which i wrote

```
fromPath='source path'
echo $fromPath
file='destination path/*.pdf'
echo $file
toPath='destination path'
echo $toPath
for i in $file;
do
  filePath=$i
  if [ -e $filePath ];
  then
    echo $filePath
    yes | cp -rf $filePath $toPath
  else
    echo 'no files'
  fi
done
```

Comment: `mv ~/node*/*.txt destinationPath/` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code:

```
find /home/andhra1 -maxdepth 3 -name "*.txt" -type f -exec mv '{}' 
destinationPath/ \;
```